# python swig : ImportError wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: python, swig, importerror

I am trying to interface from python to c++ code via swig.
I get the following error , while trying to execute my script.

```
File "./driver.py", line 4, in <module>
  from fixMessageSim import *
File "/var/user/pradyotd/testframework/fixMessageSim.py", line 12, in <module>
  import MessageFactory
File "/var/user/pradyotd/testframework/MessageFactory.py", line 25, in <module>
  _MessageFactory = swig_import_helper()
File "/var/user/pradyotd/testframework/MessageFactory.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
  _mod = imp.load_module('_MessageFactory', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /var/user/pradyotd/testframework/_MessageFactory.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`
```

when I run file on the .so I get

```
_MessageFactory.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

similarly for python

```
/usr/bin/python: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

So I am not clear why a 64-bit .so would complain.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's the interpreter you're using? Print `sys.executable` to be sure.

Comment: Yes. I am sure. thats the interpreted being used. I printed sys.executable, and that confirms the same.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're seeing without swapping around file to accidentally use a different interpreter or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear, that the interpreter I thought I was using , was not the one in the file.
This appears to be a non-issue.