# Swig Perl: wrong ELF class

Tags: c++, perl, swig, elf

I am trying to build a Perl module out of a CXX module using Swig.
There are multiple guides related to this:

1. The generic [Swig tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) with a Perl section
2. The [Swig and C++](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html) guide
3. The [Swig and Perl5](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Perl5.html) guide

I'm new to Swig and not very familiar with C(++), but I've been able to compile my module following the tutorial in [1](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html):

I created an interface file:

```
%module my_module

%{
    #include "case.h"
    #include "case.h"
    #include "lexindex.h"
    #include "intlist.h"
    #include "weight.h"
    #include "invindex.h"
    #include "winnow.h"
    #include "nbayes.h"
    #include "svmclass.h"
    #include "svm.h"
    #include "sockhelp.h"
    #include "strtok_r.h"
    extern int num_features_guess;
    void StopServerFun( int Signal );
%}
extern int num_features_guess;

class Case {
public:
    Case();
    ~Case();
};

class Feature {
public:
    Feature();
    ~Feature();
};
```

I run Swig:

```
swig -c++ -perl5 my_module.i
```

This generates the file `my_module_wrap.cxx`.
I compile:

```
g++ -c `perl -MConfig -e 'print join(" ", @Config{qw(ccflags optimize cccdlflags)}, "-I$Config{archlib}/CORE")'` my_module.cxx my_module_wrap.cxx
```

And subsequently:

```
g++ `perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{lddlflags}'` my_module.o my_module_wrap.o -o my_module.so
```

As expected, this does create the file `my_module.so`.

Then I try to use it like this:

```
$ perl
use my_module;
```

This results in the following error:

> Can't load './my_module.so' for module my_module: ./my_module.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 at /usr/net/ActivePerl-5.14.2.1402/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 191.

As you can see from the error message, I use ActivePerl v5.14.
According to the documentation, Swig should support Perl version >=5.8. Otherwise, I do not see where to dig deeper.

There is a [similar question about Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184036/python-swig-importerror-wrong-elf-class-elfclass64), but this was a user fault using different Python interpreters.

Comment: You shouldn't ask multiple questions at once, especially in the comments section.

Comment: I can't reproduce the instructions because the file `my_module.cxx` is missing.

Comment: You might have to add the current directory to shared library search path. Try run `perl` like this: `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. perl`. See [SWIG: Wrapping C++ for Perl using only a header and a shared library, can't locate loadable object error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38214651/2173773) for an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can't load './my_module.so' for module my_module: ./my_module.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

This means: you are trying to load 64-bit `my_module.so` into a 32-bit `perl` process.

You must either use 64-bit `perl`, or rebuild `my_module.so` as a 32-bit shared library (by adding `-m32` to compile and link commands).